# Properly writing characters with Dissociative Identity Disorder

Tags: characters, character-development, antagonist, videogame, representation

In my story for a game, one of the main antagonists has Dissocistive Identity Disorder. His alters are already written, but I am asking for some advice on how to properly portrayed a character with such a disorder?

For some character description:

- THERE IS NO "EVIL ALTER"; Pardon me for using all capitals, but this here is what makes my villain greatly different from the typical tropes. Rather than have a supposed evil and good side, he is just a bad person in general, and the alters all work together to achieve a bigger goal
- Speaking of tropes, the DID that the villain has is supposed to be like the real type, not the typical story-kind
- The villain will switch alters depending on the situation, either for torturing a prisoner, or trying to talk at a meeting and make a bargain
- The villain has different sexualities and racial identities, depending on the alter
- The villain overall is not me trying to demonize DID. In fact, throughout the story, the villain even mentions himself that his alters help him, even using them to trick the protagonists with the cliches when they try to enter his mind

Comment: "The villain has different sexualities and racial identities" - yeah, this is where you're going to have to be *really* careful. I can't speak as to the realism of this, but I expect a lot of people would react to it with ridicule at best, especially the differing racial identities. And depending on what those identities *are*, you could cause serious offence (for example, a white villain with an alter who speaks like a gangsta rapper).

Comment: @F1Krazy Unsure how common it is, but varying sexual/racial identities is one possible symptoms according to definitions of DID. Similarly, I knew someone (probably [BPD](https://www.helpguide.org/articles/mental-disorders/borderline-personality-disorder.htm)) and they were a (stereotypical) "homophobic white male redneck" one week, none of which described them the week before (and in stark contrast with their phases/personas that identified as LGBTQ and usually their actual race). Obviously you can't change your race, but you can take on the cultural markers that are typical of another.

Comment: You say you don't want to demonise DID, yet your villain has DID. It doesn't matter whether or not they're fighting their alters or working with them, you're still making the person with DID the baddie, and that's the problem. If you haven't already, please read this article: https://www.healthline.com/health-news/movie-split-harms-people-with-dissociative-identity-disorder#Making-the-movie. If you have read it, you're missing the point.

Comment: Why not make the person with DID the protagonist instead? Perhaps the alters help trick the villain, although you'd need to do some proper research to find out if the disorder can work like that. I don't think Stack Exchange is the best place to do research on mental health disorders generally, but DID is rare, so while there could be someone here with DID, most answers you'll get won't give you any real understanding of how to write such a character. You need to find real people with DID, and psychologists who treat them, to get anywhere close to writing such a complex condition properly.

Comment: @Mousentrude That is why I am asking about how to write someone properly with DID. I am trying to show how a portrayal where there is no "good" or "evil" alter, because the villain is just a bad person all together, and I am trying to portray it correctly.

Comment: @crafter And I'm trying to say that portraying someone with DID as the villain is problematic full stop. It doesn't matter how 'correctly' you portray them, the mere fact that they are the villain plays into the damaging stereotype.

Comment: @Mousentrude So are you saying that every mentally ill person is an angel?

Comment: Not at all. But if every media portrayal is negative, people get the impression that that's how it always is, because that's all they see ("You've got DID? Oh, like that guy in Split"). If there were plenty of portrayals of people with DID that weren't evil it wouldn't be a problem, but there aren't, and repeating the stereotype contributes to the stigma people with DID (and mentally ill people in general) already have to deal with.